# Possible to create RPi3 Wifi Access Point with Pi Hole and OpenVPN

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, vpn, pi-hole

I would like to create an all-in-one RPi-3 device running Raspbian that, when I connect to its wifi access point, will route traffic through both an external VPN (e.g. Unblock-US) and the [Pi Hole](https://pi-hole.net) ad blocker.

Is it possible to do this? I can currently run each of these individually (though I am having issues connecting to my VPN via the OpenVPN software), but am unsure whether all this software can run together simultaneously.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? (Get the VPN working properly first, though - work on one problem at a time.)

Comment: If you search google for "pihole openvpn", the first 4 results are tutorials to accomplish what you are asking about.